# Can we connect 5000kvA TR from 11KV HT line?

Tags: electrical

What is the maximum limit can use 11kV/400-230V Transformer (i.e 2000kvA~5000kVA TR) in 11KV HT line ?
What happen, if we connected 5000kVA Transformer from 11KV HT line?
It is allow or not? IF not allow ,why ?
Please advise me.
Thank you all.

Comment: Wow, is that beyond our pay grade. You need to talk to a professional.

Comment: As Daniel said, you'll need an engineer, not internet commentators. Hopefully you're not working on any of this equipment. - I don't fully understand your wording, but basically two things could happen from an undersized transformer: (A) The internal wiring is set as a percentage of how much it'll step down the voltage. If you use the wrong input, you'll get the wrong output. (B) If the transformer is nowhere near it's rating, you'll just flat out toast it and destroy the equipment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because attaching devices to an 11kV supply isn't a home-improvement (or DIY) project.

Comment: Ask your power supplier these questions. Better yet, have someone actually qualified ask your power supplier these questions.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a few things like is the transformer rated for this.
where in the world are you located? High voltage transformers are normally housed in a vault requiring trained maintenance personnel (in the U.S.).
The power company usually controls the high voltage side but not always if you have your own switch gear. Other things is this a delta-delta or delta-Y.  Are there reclosers on the input?
On the output side are you keeping your loads above or below the requirement for ground fault detection. These are just some of the questions that need to be answered. Depending on where you live it may require an engineer or a supervising electrician to evaluate the type of service/ connections and the coordination of the overload protection system. This is not something for an untrained person to even attempt.